# AVFoundation format for different aspect ratio

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I am using AVFoundation for my camera app. I am using live video frames to grab picture using AVCaptureVideoDataOutput. 
Right now i do filter all supported formats for device and then pick highest supported resolution for format.

So for example i do get 4032*3024 resolution supported format on iPhone 8/7 which i am using as active format. i do filter from videoSupportedFramRateRanges.

I would like to know how i can render video with 4:3 resolution so i can see black bars on side of camera.

I did play with AVCaptureVideoPreviewlayer properties and found that if i use resizeAspectFill it shows camera full screen but if i just dont assign then it adds black bars on side. (I assume .resize is default property) but i am not sure whether this is right approach to show/hide black bars.

In my opinion this is working because currently i am picking highest supported resolution format which in this case is 4032*3024 due to which its working since its 4:3 aspect ratio.

Basically i want make sure i show video in 4:3 format size view in some scenario with black bars and in some scenario full screen which i am already doing.

Open questions

1. Is there any way i can make sure i can show always 4:3 aspect ratio video feed.
2. How i can show black bars with 4:3
3. also after showing black bar how I can get camera area without black bars?

Thanks!

Comment: Well so far I guess adding resizeAspectFill and not adding only way to add/ hide black bars, that’s what I learned so far.  But if that’s case how I can calculate camera area rendered without black bars? 

I tried getting bounds from AVVideoPlayerLayer but I found it always send me 667*315 regardless of I add black bars or not.